# Why aren't my data points in their correct accurate clusters while using K-Means Clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, sklearn-pandas

I plotted some data points using K-Means clustering. The screenshot is available at "https://imageshack.com/i/pomMJXMkj". When I visualize these data points, it's clearly visible that many points are not in their respective clusters and this green point is one amongst them which is far away from its centroid and is clearly very near to the blue centroid. According to K-Means algorithm the point is added to that cluster with the nearest centroid. But why isn't that the case here?

The code for the following visual is mentioned below and the link for the dataset is "https://github.com/Vivek-Nimmagadda/Player-Prediction-Using-Python/blob/master/Bowlers/Bowlers.csv":

```
# Importing the Batsmen Dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv('Bowlers\Bowlers.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]].values



# Using Elbow Method to find the optimal number of Clusters

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

wcss = []

for i in range(1, 11):

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)

    kmeans.fit(X)

    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)

plt.title('The Elbow Method')

plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')

plt.ylabel('WCSS')

plt.show()



# Fitting K-Meaens Clustering Algorithm to the Dataset

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)

y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)



# Visualising the Clusters

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 0,2], X[y_kmeans == 0,4], s = 100, c = 'blue', label = 'Good Form')

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 1,2], X[y_kmeans == 1,4], s = 100, c = 'purple', label = 'Average Touch')

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 2,2], X[y_kmeans == 2,4], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Peek Form')

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 3,2], X[y_kmeans == 3,4], s = 100, c = 'red', label = 'Poor Form')

plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 2], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 4], s = 150, c = 'cyan', label = 'Centroids')

plt.title('Recent Form of Bowlers Based on their Stats')

plt.xlabel('Wickets')

plt.ylabel('Average')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

My expected result is to visualize all the data points accurately in their respective clusters. Whereas it's randomly displaying the points. Can anyone please help me in correcting this error?

Comment: You can try using a for loop in the plotting itself. This link might be useful to you.
http://benalexkeen.com/k-means-clustering-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're clustering a data set based on features in 7 dimensions/variables. If we were able to view 7 dimensions at a time, you would see that these points do actually cluster together correctly.

But unfortunately we can't. The plot you are viewing contains just two of those dimensions, and information contained in the other dimensions (variables) is lost. This loss of information makes it look as if the points don't cluster together, but in their original higher-dimensional space they do, which is what was found by your clustering algorithm.

A dimensionality reduction technique such as principal component analysis (also available in sklearn), can reduce the data down to 2 dimensions more "effectively", projecting the data to the axis containing the most variance in the original space. But even here you might not see the clustering behaviour you desire. If this is the case, you will just have to believe your clustering algorithm!